# Do I have to assign the data from sc.nextLine() to a variable before I use it?

Tags: java

So far, every time I have used a scanner object I have assigned the input to a new string variable like:

```
String word = reader.nextLine();
```

and then if I want to use the input in an if statement I would write:

```
if(word.isEmpty()){}
```

but this seems almost like an extra step instead of just doing:

```
if(reader.nextLine().isEmpty()){}
```

however, when I try this I usually get some kind of problem in my program function. Is there a way to do this by skipping the String that I will never use again?

This is the code that I am trying to use without the String objects:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordsInReverseOrder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(true){
            System.out.println("Type a word: ");

            if(reader.nextLine().isEmpty()){

                Collections.reverse(words);

                for(String word1 : words){

                    System.out.println(word1);
                }
                break;
            }

            else{
                words.add(reader.nextLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the problem you are facing in the question as well

Comment: That line should work fine assuming there is a next line to get

Comment: `Scanner#nextLine` may throw an exception, so it makes good logical sense to separate the code which calls it from the code which uses the output.

Comment: "*however, when I try this I usually get some kind of problem in my program function.*" - Please be more specific. What kind of problem? Is an `Exception` thrown? If so, please include the stack trace.

Comment: [Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, I updated my post with the code that I am trying. When I create a String object and use it then it functions smoothly but when I do the code above I usually have the program ask for two lines of input before iterating the loop again and it also never reaches the if statement.

Comment: It ask to enter two times because on time in the if condition and one time in the else body. If you want to use the same string in the both situation the only solution is to affect the input to a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to do something with the scanned word **and** want to check isEmpty() than you need a variable to access the word twice.

So, if you do more than one thing, you need a variable. If you do just one thing, you can 'inline' the variable.

The answer to your question is 'Yes'. When you do not need the content of the first  word / line, the you can 'inline' your variable, which means that there is no need for a variable.

Comment: "*Is there a way to do this by skipping the String that I will never use again?*" - Your post does not answer this question.

Comment: I think I see now. So, the if clause reader.nextLine() and the else reader.nextLine() are two completely separate things? I thought it would just take the user input and check everything.

Comment: Hi @Turing85 sorry for not beeing concrete enough. The answer to the question is 'Yes'. The way to do this is to 'inline' the variable, which means that there is no need for a variable.

Comment: Then you should [edit] your answer and add this information =)